# How can I "select the proper test sample size" to "achieve the best classification quality"?

Tags: self-study, classification, confidence-interval, error

Homework disclaimer. We were given 10k rows of sample training data.

> The task is to train some well-known classifiers (as listed below),
>   test their performance and  estimate the expected misclassification
>   error using Hoeffding inequality for possible new cases. The aim is to
>   achieve the best classification quality (understood as the lowest
>   expected generalization error). This should be achieved by testing
>   classifiers using the sample split and selecting the proper test
>   sample size. When solving a task, do not use crossvalidation. It is
>   not necessary to optimize the values of classifiers parameters while
>   solving the task.

I fail to understand what is being asked here.

How can *selecting the proper test sample size* do any good with regard to *achieving the best classification quality (understood as the lowest expected generalization error)*?

To my understanding, the more data I use as training data the better classifier I am going to obtain - so if I am to, as the assignment asks, try to obtain the best classifier through manipulating the test sample size, the solution is as easy as it is absurd: use *all* data as training data and *no* data as testing data. But the tradeoff is that the more data I use as testing data, the better I can estimate the quality of the classifier (the smaller confidence interval I am going to obtain). So if I maximize the classifier's quality in the way described above I won't be able to estimate it!

Now the task mentions the [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality). But Hoeffding's inequality can tell me how big of a test sample size I have to have to obtain a given confidence interval for a given estimated quality. But I still can't see how to use it: the task doesn't put a constraint like "you must be able to claim with at least 80% confidence that the actual accuracy of your classifier differs no more than 5 percent points from your estimated accuracy". If such a constraint was present then the task would make more sense to me.

Also, the tasks asks me to report the method I used to estimate the minimum generalization error.

Finally, just in case this is relevant: The three simple classifiers I have to use are: Naive Bayes, kNN and decision tree.

What am I failing to understand here?